# I want to identify an list item from Audit log

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site, audit-log-reports

I'm using SharePointOnline's Modern UI.

I want to identify user updated items from the audit log.

In the audit log, in the case of a document library, the file name is output so I can identify the item, but how can I identify the item in the case of a list?

From the name, it looks like I could use ListItemUniqueId, but I don't know how to use it.

I am very grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Per my research, I think ListItemUniqueId is generated through audit log report, rather than the identification of the list item.

Please use the following powershell to get the list title:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$siteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xx"  
$userId = "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"  
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userId, $pwd)  
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)  
$ctx.credentials = $creds  
try{  
    $lists = $ctx.web.Lists  
    #$list = $lists.GetByTitle("list666")  
    $guid = [GUID] ("8A3AE548-0F20-4705-A047-5CF855543704")
    $list = $lists.GetById($guid)

    $ctx.load($list) 
    $ctx.executeQuery()  
    $list.Title

}  
catch{  
    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red  
}
```

Then find the list and check the item id which has been updated as shown below:

[image]